# Trying to redirect signup form to login page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redirect, redux, jsx

I have a react app that I'm trying to redirect the user to the login page after the user submits the signup information. I was able to redirect from my login page to my dashboard but not working on signup page.

These are separate parts of my code that I'm having the redirect issue with

```
.then(this.redirectLogin)
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        this.setState({
          showError: true,
          errorMessage: "Username already taken, please try again"
        });
      });
    this.addTeam(this.state.username);
  }

  redirectLogin() {
    window.location = "/login";
  }



<form className="formContainer" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        {this.state.showError && (
          <p className="error">{this.state.errorMessage}</p>
        )}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using [`react-router`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router) for your routes. It's considered the standard for routing within a React application. Once you've setup your routing, you can wrap your component with `withRouter`:

```
export default withRouter(YourComponent)
```

Then you'll have access to the router history from your props, and can just push your route:

```
this.props.history.push('/dashboard');
```

You can find more information about `react-router` [here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start).